# Razor making the build time longer

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, build

I have just switched from old-style to razor.
Since this point the compile time has become much slower, is there any thing I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A couple options:

- Do you have `MvcBuildViews` in your project file set to `true`? You could set that to `false` if so and just compile at runtime.
- You could pre-generate your Razor views using: [Razor Generator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) (also on NuGet)